# Disable new email envelope overlay on Outlook 2016 for Mac dock icon

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

How can I turn off the "new email" envelope overlay that appears on top of the dock icon in Outlook 2016 for Mac? I turned off all notifications in Outlook's preferences and turned off the unread mail badge counter in Mac OS's notifications settings, but this annoying envelope keeps appearing when a new message arrives:

[image: new email envelope overlay]

Comment: Did you solve the problem. The notification settings do not help I know. The standard red bubble icon is removed, but the white envelope keeps coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on Outlook and select 'show package contents'.  Navigate to Resources and find the file called 'new mail badge.png'.  Rename this file (eg to 'new mail badge1.png').  That's it.

Comment: Ugly hack, but this actually works. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You edit the system's Notification preferences for Outlook (or any other app.) [enter link description here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/29/disable-red-badge-app-icons-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Too bad, this isn't what the OP had in mind. It removes the red counter, but not the outlook-specific envelope.

Comment: Please enter link description here...